# Biztalk XLANG transform() output the same random value in a loop inside Biztalk orchestration

Tags: c#, biztalk

I wrote a map to generate an HL7 message header (MSH).
For the MSH.10 segment, by definition should be unique so I put the following in my map.

```
    public string MessageControlId()
    {
       //return System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");


       string firstPart = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
       string middlePart = new Random().Next( 1000, 9999 ).ToString();
       string lastPart = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ffff");
        
       return firstPart + middlePart + lastPart;
    }
```

[image]

Then in my orchestration I call the header map multiple time in a loop.  My goal is to generate multiple HL7 messages, each with its own message header and a unique MSH.10 value.

[image]

The code below is based on [Microsoft Biztalk XLANG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/xlang-s-statements) syntax which invokes the map to transform and create the message header via the transform() statement.

```
tMapType = System.Type.GetType(msgBre.HeaderMapName);

transform (msgHeader) = tMapType(msgBilling);
```

However, when I tested this out I see multiple HL7 message generated but many of them have duplicate value in term of their MSH.10 segment.  I grouped them in different color below.

[image]

I expect separate value each time because in my code I generate a random number between 1000 and 9999.  Plus I also generate the time value to the thousand of a second.

Do you know why this occur? My only theory is when I call the tranform() function, it does not really invoke the map to recreate the header each time...that seems wrong to me.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @hulihunskeli input, I was able to solve this by going into my orchestration in Biztalk and just prior of loop repetition I added a 200ms delay and that seems to solve it.  I guess this is one of those things where the processing time of the loop is just too quick for the function to generate a new object which ensure a unique number.

[image]

Comment: Why  does your firstPart not include the time **HHmmss** ?

Comment: @sqlab It is just a test of mine, I originally have yyyyMMddHHmmssffff but it produces the same issue so I tried to debug it by introducing the random 4 digits number as a middle part and I still have the same issues.  This proves to me this is not being run each time I call transform()

Comment: Why not just have a sequence number instead of a random number?  You can increment that sequence number inside the loop.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I original had yyyyMMddHHmmssffff which is the datetimestamp down to the 4 digits of a second which I think should be enough to capture and generate a unique value.  To your point , the loop is at my orchestration level that calls the header map to be transformed and I am unsure how to capture an orchestration counter value and place it within a map.

Comment: Use a distinguished field, make sure you are mapping a default value to the field, and have an expression inside the construct & after the map that assigns the value to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Random object which is a pseudo-random number generator, so it returns the same sequence of numbers with a same seed. You are not giving a seed explicitly to the constructor, so it uses default seed which is based on a system clock. If you are creating Random objects in a tight loop with a default seed then next() function will return you the same number multiple times, which I think is what happens here.

You should either give unique seed explicitly or use the same Random object all the time (if it is possible).

Comment: I originally use date time stamp with format yyyyMMddHHmmssffff and it has the same issue.  If the Random object behaves as per your suggestion, shouldn't I get the same value all the time? instead I get "some" that are the same and some are different.

Comment: In C# documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-6.0) for Random this is stated: "On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are likely to have identical seed values.". So if you are instantiating Random objects within milliseconds from each other, you will get the same seed and because of that the same "random" number.